# Crate custom tail in just_the_tooltip Library

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tooltip

I am using [JustTheTooltip](https://pub.dev/packages/just_the_tooltip) library. There is a built in function to create a custom tail, but I can't figure out how to create the path relative to the tooltip. I need a custom triangle to the left.

Docs:

> ```
> Tail Builder If you'd like a custom tail (the nub on the end dialog bubble) drawn on your tooltip, you can pass through your own
> ```
>
> tailBuilder. The JustTheInterface.defaultTailBuilder (default) shows
> how to simply draw and return a path for your custom tails:
>
> ```
> Path defaultTailBuilder(Offset tip, Offset point2, Offset point3) {
> return Path() ..moveTo(tip.dx, tip.dy) ..lineTo(point2.dx, point2.dy) ..lineTo(point3.dx, point3.dy) ..close(); }
> ```

I am trying this:

```
JustTheTooltip(
  preferredDirection: AxisDirection.right,
  tailBuilder: (_, __, ___) => _customTailBuilder(Offset(100, 100), Offset(170, 150), Offset(170, 50),),
  ................
);
```

And _customTailBuilder is the same as above, in the docs.

```
Path _customTailBuilder(Offset tip, Offset point2, Offset point3) {  
 return Path()
     ..moveTo(tip.dx, tip.dy)
     ..lineTo(point2.dx, point2.dy)
     ..lineTo(point3.dx, point3.dy)
     ..close(); 
}
```

I need the triangle to be relative to the tooltip, I don't know how to get the postition, thank you

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @Mr.Tacio no, I wasn't

Comment: I have tried following your code and tweak it. I posted what I have used in mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have done.

```
  Path defaultTailBuilder(Offset tip, Offset point2, Offset point3) {
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Path()
      ..moveTo(tip.dx + size - 100, tip.dy)
      ..lineTo(point2.dx + size - 100, point2.dy)
      ..lineTo(point3.dx + size - 100, point3.dy)
      ..close();
  }
```

Comment: yes, but that is a fixed point, right? it is not relative to the dynamic position of tooltip, is it?

Comment: you can try to add the size so that it is dynamic